# Python Popen Cannot Find the File Specified

Tags: python, subprocess, popen

I have the following code

```
pathToFile = "R:\T2 Output\12345--01--Some File 1--ABCD.mp4"
process = subprocess.Popen(['ffprobe.exe', '-show_streams', '"'+pathToFile+'"'],
    shell=True, stdout=subprocess.PIPE, stderr=subprocess.PIPE)
```

I get the error:

```
[Error 2] The system cannot find the file specified
```

What I have tried:

- Changing shell=True to shell=False
- Combining the command into a single string instead of using a list (I even print it to screen, and I can copy and paste into a command prompt where the file runs and gives the expected output (no error)
- I made sure that ffprobe.exe is located in the PATH and can be executed from the command line without specifying a directory

Things of note:

- The file is located on a mapped network drive (R)
- The file has spaces in the filename, this is why I surrounded it by quotes.

I'm sure I'm missing something simple.  Can anyone point me in the right direction?  I've done quite a lot of searching on this site and others and trying suggestions.

Comment: in addition to escaping backslashes in the string, you should drop unnecessary quotes `'"'` around `pathToFile` and drop unnecessary argument `shell=True` in the `Popen` call.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

The `\` symbol counts as an escape character in python, use `r` to turn that off:

```
pathToFile = r"R:\T2 Output\12345--01--Some File 1--ABCD.mp4"
```

Comment: That helped!  Now it says "ffprobe.exe is not recognized as an internal or external command, operable program or batch file."

I have put ffprobe: in the same directory, put the full path (with an r in front) to ffprobe:  (e.g. C:\somefolder\ffprobe), put a relative path in front of the name ".\ffprobe.exe", put a copy of ffprobe.exe in C:\Windows\System32, and made sure that directory was in PATH, and added an 'r' in front of 'ffprobe.exe' for good measure.

It still doesn't recognize it. At least I moved to the next error though.  Thanks for the help!

Comment: @cyram are you running into issues with spaces in the folder names?